# Object Detection and Recognition in JS

Tags: javascript, computer-vision, object-detection, p5.js

I wanted to develop object detection system using ml5 & p5.js,where I can upload an image and system can provide me an output image with Rectangle around objects in image. Yolo and Cocossd datasets are working fine for recognition an object in image.

Like this image object is being identified:

[image: screenshot]

But these datasets are not giving me results for detection where there is text or object with text. As I am expecting system to identify each word of text as different object, like for below image :

[image: Image to detect]

Result should be like this:

1. Rectangle around K
2. Rectangle around F
3. Rectangle around C
4. and one Rectangle around  logo of KFC

Please help regarding this or suggest any other system which i can use in PHP/Js to detect objects in image.

```js
let img;
let detector;
function preload(){
img = loadImage('e.jpeg');  
detector = ml5.objectDetector('yolo');
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  image(img,0,0);
  detector.detect(img,gotDetections);

}
 function gotDetections(error, result){
   if(error){
     console.log(error)
   }
   console.log(result)
   drawResults(result);
  //    for (let i = 0 ; i< result.length; i++){
  //   let object = result[i];
  //   stroke(0,255,255);
  //   strokeWeight(4);
  //   noFill();
  //   rect(object.x ,object.y,object.width,object.height);
  // }
 }
function drawResults(results) {
    results.forEach((result) => {

        // Generates a random color for each object
        const r = Math.random()*256|0;
        const g = Math.random()*256|0;
        const b = Math.random()*256|0;

        // Draw the text
        stroke(0, 0, 0);
        strokeWeight(2);
        textSize(16);
        fill(r, g, b);
  text(`${result.label} (${result.confidence.toFixed(2)}%)`, result.x, result.y - 10);

        // Draw the rectangle stroke
        noFill();
        strokeWeight(3);
        stroke(r, g, b);
        rect(result.x, result.y, result.width, result.height);
    });
};
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  
  <body>
    <main>
      
    </main>
    
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use `OCR` to detect text characters. I am wondering how did you come to the result that you would be able to use a model for object detection to detect texts!!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. if there is an object like bull ,bat or fox in image. will it be recognized using OCR?

Comment: just like image uploaded 'Image to Detect'. as a result i need to detect the KFC and also the picture in it. can i do it?

Comment: OCR is known to be used to recognize text characters and strings, not objects!
[tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract#running-tesseract) this is a library for it!

Comment: You have to run two models on the same image. One for detecting texts and the other to detect the image. Specifically, to detect the `KFC logo` you have to train a new model where you train it using some pictures for the same logo in different situations. For this, I recommend sth called [Transfer Learning](https://github.com/BrooksIan/LogoTL)